# DHIS2 Version 2.30: Unable to see aggregate data values in pivot table

Tags: dhis2

I have an issue on my dhis2 instance. I am unable to see my aggregate data values in the pivot table application even though I am able to see them in the data entry application. I have tried checking the aggregation levels, the user permissions, assigned org units, cleared cache, run analytics and even switched my browser to incognito, none of which are helping. my data elements are of type Text and all of them are using option sets. I am feeling as if there is something I am missing but do not know what.

Will be grateful for any help I can get on this.